# Heightmap generation using midpoint displacement

Tags: random, image, f#

I am writing a program to generate a height map following the midpoint displacement algorithm (somewhat similar to diamond-square).

I'm at the point where I have a recursive program that paints the whole map but still needs some modifications to provide the desired result.

Before I do, I would like a code review on what I have so far to make sure everything so far is ok.

**height_map.fs**

```
module HeightMap

// contains the height map types and common functions that can be re-used for 
// different generation algorithms

type HeightMap = {Size:int; Map:float array} with     
    member this.Get x y =
        this.Map.[x * this.Size + y]      

    member this.Set x y value =
        this.Map.[x * this.Size + y] <- value

// returns a square matrix of size 2^n + 1
let newHeightMap n : HeightMap =
    let size = ( pown 2 n ) + 1
    {Size = size; Map = Array.zeroCreate (size * size)}  

// normalize a single value to constrain it's value between 0.0 and 1.0
let normalizeValue v =
    match v with
    | v when v < 0.0 -> 0.0
    | v when v > 1.0 -> 1.0
    | _ -> v

// converts a float point ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 to a rgb value
// 0.0 represents black and 1.0 white. The conversion is in greyscale 
let convertFloatToRgb (pct:float) : int * int * int =
    let greyscale = int (float 255 * pct)
    (greyscale, greyscale, greyscale)

// returns the average between two values    
let avgf (a:float) (b:float) =
    (a + b) / 2.0

// find the middle between two points in our map
let avgi (a:int) (b:int) =
    (a + b) / 2

// returns a floating number which is generated using bounds as a control of the range of possible values
let randomize (rnd:System.Random) (bound:int) : float = 
    float (rnd.Next(-bound, bound) / bound)
```

**midpoint_displacement.fs**

```
module MidpointDisplacement

open HeightMap

// set the four corners to random values
let initCorners (hm:HeightMap) =
    let rnd = System.Random()    
    let size = hm.Size   

    hm.Set 0 0 (rnd.NextDouble())
    hm.Set 0 (size - 1) (rnd.NextDouble())
    hm.Set (size - 1) 0 (rnd.NextDouble())
    hm.Set (size - 1) (size - 1) (rnd.NextDouble())

// set the middle values between each corner (c1 c2 c3 c4)
// variation is a function that is applied on each pixel to modify it's value
let middle (hm:HeightMap) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) (variation) =
    // set left middle
    if hm.Get x1 (avgi y1 y3) = 0.0 then 
        hm.Set x1 (avgi y1 y3) (avgf (hm.Get x1 y1) (hm.Get x3 y3) |> variation |> normalizeValue)      

    // set upper middle
    if hm.Get (avgi x1 x2) y1 = 0.0 then
        hm.Set (avgi x1 x2) y1 (avgf (hm.Get x1 y1) (hm.Get x2 y2) |> variation |> normalizeValue)

    // set right middle
    if hm.Get x2 (avgi y2 y4) = 0.0 then 
        hm.Set x2 (avgi y2 y4) (avgf (hm.Get x2 y2) (hm.Get x4 y4) |> variation |> normalizeValue)

    // set lower middle
    if hm.Get (avgi x3 x4) y3 = 0.0 then
        hm.Set (avgi x3 x4) y3 (avgf (hm.Get x3 y3) (hm.Get x4 y4) |> variation |> normalizeValue)           

// set the center value of the current matrix to the average of all middle values + variation function
let center (hm:HeightMap) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) (variation) =
    // average height of left and right middle points
    let avgHorizontal = avgf (hm.Get x1 (avgi y1 y3)) (hm.Get x2 (avgi y2 y4))
    let avgVertical = avgf (hm.Get (avgi x1 x2) y1) (hm.Get (avgi x3 x4) y3)

    // set center value
    hm.Set (avgi x1 x4) (avgi y1 y4) (avgf avgHorizontal avgVertical |> variation |> normalizeValue) 

let rec displace (hm) (x1, y1) (x4, y4) (rnd) =
    let ulCorner = (x1, y1) 
    let urCorner = (x4, y1)
    let llCorner = (x1, y4)
    let lrCorner = (x4, y4)

    // the lambda passed in as a parameter is temporary until a define a better function
    middle hm ulCorner urCorner llCorner lrCorner (fun x -> x + (randomize rnd 100))
    center hm ulCorner urCorner llCorner lrCorner (fun x -> x + (randomize rnd 100))

    if x4 - x1 >= 2 then
        let xAvg = avgi x1 x4
        let yAvg = avgi y1 y4
        displace hm (x1, y1) (xAvg, yAvg) rnd
        displace hm (xAvg, y1) (x4, yAvg) rnd
        displace hm (x1, yAvg) (xAvg, y4) rnd
        displace hm (xAvg, yAvg) (x4, y4) rnd

let generate hm =
    initCorners hm    

    let size = hm.Size - 1
    let rnd = System.Random()

    displace hm (0, 0) (size, size) rnd
```

Among other things, two things seem particularly wrong to me but I don't know how to refactor them.

1. I have both an `avgf` and `avgi` function because of the division by 2 or 2.0 which depends on the input type.
2. `|> variation |> normalizeValue` is repeated 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can have a single two-point average function that works for both float and int, as well as other numeric types:

```
// returns the average between two values    
let inline avg (a:^n) (b:^n) : ^n =
    (a + b) / (LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne)
```

As far as the repetition of `|> variation |> normalizeValue` I don't have anything super-clever to suggest, but you could shorten it by using the `>>` operator to combine those two functions, something like this:

```
let middle (hm:HeightMap) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) (variation) =
    let vn = variation >> normalizeValue

    // set left middle
    if hm.Get x1 (avg y1 y3) = 0.0 then 
        hm.Set x1 (avg y1 y3) (avg (hm.Get x1 y1) (hm.Get x3 y3) |> vn)      

    // set upper middle
    if hm.Get (avg x1 x2) y1 = 0.0 then
        hm.Set (avg x1 x2) y1 (avg (hm.Get x1 y1) (hm.Get x2 y2) |> vn)

    // set right middle
    if hm.Get x2 (avg y2 y4) = 0.0 then 
        hm.Set x2 (avg y2 y4) (avg (hm.Get x2 y2) (hm.Get x4 y4) |> vn)

    // set lower middle
    if hm.Get (avg x3 x4) y3 = 0.0 then
        hm.Set (avg x3 x4) y3 (avg (hm.Get x3 y3) (hm.Get x4 y4) |> vn)
```

Instead of calling a function to convert a literal integer to a float with `int (float 255 * pct)` I would probably use a literal float: `int (255.0 * pct)`.

Your `randomize` function mostly only returns 0.0 because it's doing integer division. Dividing an integer less than your bound by the bound, which is an integer, will return a number less than 1, which will be truncated to zero by the integer division. You might find this version a little closer to your intent.

```
let randomize (rnd:System.Random) (bound:int) : float =
    let max = float bound
    let min = -max 
    min + (rnd.NextDouble() * ((1.0 + max) - min))
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do when you see a boilerplate code is to represent code as data.
So your function middle is quite simple iterate all sides of a square(represented as a pair of points) use side points and a point between them and apply change. In short you could write something like that

```
let middle (hm:HeightMap) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) (variation) =
    let points = [|x1, y1; x2, y2; x4, y4; x3, y3; x1, y1|]//clockwise iterate sides
    for i in 0..3 do
        let x1, y1 = points.[i]
        let x2, y2 = points.[i + 1]
        let mx, my = avgi x1 x2, avgi y1 y2

        if hm.Get mx my = 0.0 then 
            hm.Set mx my (avgf (hm.Get x1 y1) (hm.Get x2 y2) |> variation |> normalizeValue)
```

One additional trick when you work with an array with some cursor inside it and have to do some recursive work then you could apply comonads.